Is it more grammatically correct to ask "When do your exams end?" or "When do your exams finish?"
If neither of these sentences are correct, what would be the correct way to ask this question?

Why do you think they're different, grammatically or semantically?

The duplicate is not close enough. Here, "When do your exams end?" asks when the series is over (when they are done). "When do your exams finish?" should be "When do you finish your exams?" because you are the acting agent.

When are your exams over? Also idiomatic. Or, when is exam week over?

Unlike the duplicate, this is an intransitive use (come to an end) - but I find both verbs equally idiomatic.

Thank you Yosef, Xanne and Kate. Your answers have been helpful. KillingTime, I'm not sure, but I want to know which one is less idiomatic.
